# Can you flick the idleTimerDisabled boolean on and off from within your app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer, sleep

For example I have a game with a menu screen and then I have the game itself. I want the timer disabled whilst playing the game but enabled when in the menu screen. I currently have the following code in my app delegate that disables the timer:

```
application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do it in your app delegate, why wouldn't you be able to do it from anywhere else?  The only question is how to get a reference to `application`:

```
[Application sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

Comment: I think you meant:
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to NO when you show the menu. You can enable and disable the timer as you like, with the code you show.

Comment: I was under the impression you could only use this code in the app delegate?

Comment: No, as Ed also answered, you can do this from anywhere. The code then is just `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES/NO;`

Generally, the app does not care where you do your stuff. It's only a matter of getting the right object (the UIApplication singleton in this case). :)